# Veepeak V11 ELM327 bluetooth connection problem with Raspberry pi4

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi4, bluez, obd-ii, hci

i am writing here because i have an issue with the connection of an OBD device (Veepeak V11) to my raspberry pi4.
When i connect the device to my phone or laptop it works perfectly but on the raspberry i found a lot of issues. Speaking of software, i am using basic linux cli commands for bluetooth: bluetoothctl and hcitool.
The version of my kernel is above 6 so i have the can bus new drivers (changed after kernel 6 from what i have understood). My bluez version is 5.55.
With both commands, when i do "scan on" the device is found. If i do "pair" the device pairs and it even ask for code 1234 so it is working. But when a do "connect" the connection initially is ok but after 5 seconds it disconnects automatically. Searching on internet i found out that maybe this is an hardware or driver issue so i want to ask here before buying a new OBD device.
In my opionion this is a software problem and not hardware.
I send an allegate with the screenshot of the failed connection and one with the output of the command : btmon. Hoping this will help.

PS: i already tried to resolve the bluez error but without success. And i am not sure if  this was the cause of the issue.

Down here you can find the screenshots of the error on the bluetoothctl connect and the output of btmon in the interesting part.

[Bluetoothctl connect error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYdWp.jpg)

[Btmon output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yymwX.jpg)

I tried all the easy solutions: checking bluetooth status and errors, checked versions, checked physical connection, tried the device with other devices and it works, delayed the bthelper service of 2 seconds to avoid problems with the processes. Used btmon and bettercap to have more informations but i had no success with the resolution of the problem.

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

5 seconds sounds like an inactivity timeout. Many classic BT devices have such a timeout. Try gathering a PID frequently and check whether it still hangs up.